# Swiping back to dismiss a child VC while passing data

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have a Navigation Controller that contains 1 Parent VC and 1 Child VC. Data is passed between the two. On the Parent VC, I am passing data to the Child VC via prepareForSegue. On the Child VC back to Parent VC, I am passing data via a custom back button unwind segue.

Passing the data back and forth work great. However, I would like the Child VC to be able to be swiped right to close, while still passing the same information as in the unwind segue.

**Is there a way to pass the data back to the parent using a swipe, along with being able to press the back button unwind?** The only gesture method I am using is gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, which allows the Child VC to be swiped to the right.

```
extension ChildVC: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

For reference, here's my unwind:

```
@IBAction func unwindfromChild(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let CVC = sender.source as? ChildVC {
        print("Unwind")
        dataReceived() // do stuff with the received data
    }
}
```

Comment: why not create a custom unwind segue ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan And call the custom unwind segue where? I just need to pass data back to the Parent VC through swiping to dismiss the Child VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a slightly different approach. I fully removed the unwind segue. Passing the data through delegation. The delegate method is called in `navigationController:willShow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach a [swipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) to your view, name the unwind segue in Interface Builder, and inside the target function [trigger the unwind segue](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/).

Comment: This does not work. Adding a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer prevents the ChildVC from being able to be swiped to the right.